# Is the speed/performance of webgl on RaspianOS (Debian64) via VirtualBox the same as on an actual RaspberryPi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, webgl, virtualbox, raspbian

My question is simple. If anyone knows the answer I'd appreciate input. I'm running Raspian OS (Debian64bit) via VirtualBox and it seems to be running my webgl code fine. But I'd like to know if the performance would be the same on a Raspberry Pi running the same OS. I don't know if the specs matter. let me know if they do and I can post them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No its not, you're not emulating the hardware of a raspberry pi but just the architecture.

Comment: should i expect worse or better performance from webgl and the gpu? or is there no way of telling?

Comment: to clarify i mean should i expect better or worse performance on the Pi?  What percentage increase/decrease in performance would you say occurs on average for gpu intensive applications?

Comment: There is no average, there is too many factors involved, specs of your host system, settings in virtualbox, driver versions, then for the emulated and actual raspberry PI: OS version, driver versions, browser version, background processes running, environment temperature and last but not least the efficiency of your javascript code, the efficiency of your glsl code and then the general silicone lottery. For cross platform development there's just no way around testing your application on the actual target platform.